# Drilling through namespaces with xml2js

Tags: node.js, namespaces, xml2js

I have some xml that I have parsed using npms [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js). It has a few namespaces in the xml and when I parse it and inspect the results I get this...

[image]

Cool. I can go to steps deep by doing this console.log(result['bpr:release']['bpr:contents']) which yeilds this..

[image]

Want I want to do now is try and drill into those child nodes like process and process group but I can't figure out how or find an documentation on it. I tried things like 
result['bpr:release']['bpr:contents'].process and result['bpr:release']['bpr:contents']['process'] and neither works. What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the JSON [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

I've found this will always fully display the output. The regular methods aren't reliable for getting nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was just going down the wrong paths. This was the correct way...

result['bpr:release']['bpr:contents'][0]['process'][0]

Respect arrays